# Asp.net Update labels based on event

Tags: asp.net

i am facing one problem.

what i have to do is. There is a button on page which starts the processing of some jobs.

when i press start button i am calling ProcessJobs method of my Business layer which raises an event having total number of jobs. I have to display this count in ListBox control.

After this in processing of job there are several status messages raised via same event. these messages should be displayed at web form in list box control

But i am not getting web page to update itself. I also added timer control and refreshes the page after 1 sec. but page is not being updated.

here is code

Default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class xxxxx: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private xxxx manager;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.manager == null)
        {
            manager = new xxxx();
            this.manager.ProcessEmailEvent += new EventHandler<EventArg<string>>(manager_ProcessEmailEvent);
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.btnStop.Visible = false;

        }
    }

    void manager_ProcessEmailEvent(object sender, EventArg<string> e)
    {
        this.lblStatus.Text = this.lblStatus.Text + "<br>" + e.Data;
    }

    protected void processEmailTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int tickCount = this.manager.EmailProcessCount;
        int totalEmailCount = this.manager.TotalEmailsCount;

        this.lblProcessEmail.Text = string.Format("Processing Emails <b>{0}</b> of <b>{1}</b>", tickCount, totalEmailCount);

    }
    protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.processEmailTimer.Enabled = true;
        this.btnStart.Visible = false;
        this.btnStop.Visible = true;
this.manager.ProcessEmails(this.chkValidateEmail.Checked, this.chkTesting.Checked);

    }
    protected void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.processEmailTimer.Enabled = false;
        this.btnStart.Visible = true;
        this.btnStop.Visible = false;
        this.manager.Stop();
    }
```

Here is business Logic for processing emails

```
public event EventHandler<EventArg<string>> ProcessEmailEvent;

    public void InvokeProcessEmailEvent(EventArg<string> e)
    {
        EventHandler<EventArg<string>> handler = ProcessEmailEvent;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

public void ProcessEmails(bool validateSenderEmail, bool deleteEmailAfterProcess)
    {
        // Creaate pop3 Client
        POP3_Client popClient = new POP3_Client();

        // Connect to POP3 host
        popClient.Connect(Utility.POP3Host, Utility.POP3Port, Utility.UseSSL);

        // Authenticate email address and password
        popClient.Authenticate(Utility.EmailAddress, Utility.Password, false);

        // Get Email count
        int msgCount = popClient.Messages.Count;

// Raising event to update status on default.aspx

        this.InvokeProcessEmailEvent(new EventArg<string>("Emails : " + msgCount));

        TotalEmailsCount = msgCount;


        // Start emai Processing
        processEmailStarted = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < msgCount; i++)
        {
            this.EmailProcessCount = i + 1;        

// Raising event to update status on default.aspx
            this.InvokeProcessEmailEvent(new EventArg<string>("Getting Email " + (i + 1)));

            // Get message
            var msg = popClient.Messages[i];

            // Get Email header
            Mail_Message mime = Mail_Message.ParseFromByte(msg.HeaderToByte());

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            this.InvokeProcessEmailEvent(new EventArg<string>("--------------------------------"));


            this.InvokeProcessEmailEvent(new EventArg<string>("From :  " + mime.From.ToString()));


            this.InvokeProcessEmailEvent(new EventArg<string>("Subject :  " + mime.Subject.ToString()));



            this.InvokeProcessEmailEvent(new EventArg<string>("Date :  " + mime.Date.ToString()));


            this.InvokeProcessEmailEvent(new EventArg<string>("Size (KB):  " + (msg.Size / (decimal)1000).ToString()));           

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code so we can see exactly what is going on?

Comment: Is this message that you want to change in an update panel?  What does your aspx page look like?

Comment: yes there is update panel and button and listbox and timer is in update panel

Comment: Is the timer set as an async postback trigger for the update panel?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your basic approach to how these events get raised.  High on that list would be making the manager be a singleton that lives outside of the page.  The way you have your code, the manager object is instantiated on every page request (including the timer tick).  Check out this article on Long Running Processes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163553.aspx